# Does an NSOperation spawn a new thread?

Tags: multithreading, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Very simply, is there a one to one connection between a thread(or NSThread) and an NSOperation? Or is it abstracted out an operation is kind of a task that can be picked up and run by multiple threads in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a one-to-one connection, no. The advantage of using `NSOperation` subclasses is that you're not required to manage the multi-threading yourself. Apple even (confusingly) defines the typical `NSOperation` subclass (i.e., one overriding the `-main` method) as *non-concurrent*, not because it doesn't support concurrency, but because the details of concurrency are managed by the superclass:

> Don’t be confused by the terminology: just because an operation is non-concurrent, does not mean it cannot be executed concurrently, it simply means that you don't have to handle the concurrency yourself.

In that sense, an `NSOperation` subclass is much more like the target object of NSThread's
`detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`.

The alternative, if you want control over how the concurrency behaves, is to override `-start` and set up concurrency as needed before invoking `-main`.

Here's a very good overview: [Managing Concurrency with NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html)

Comment: so which line in this document says that there is no one-to-one connection? where it says that overriding -main is non-concurrent? non-concurrent just means it can run in parallel, not necessarily that it does or does not run on the same nsthread, correct?

Comment: I've quoted from the documentation and clarified the distinction.